# adding regex int to a var

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to make a irc bot that takes input like this `user: +1` I want to have a end result where I can have a main number being added to, from the # someone types with +#.

expected output: `#x added: 1 rep: 1 executed[+]` second execution
`#x added: 1 rep: 2 executed[+]`

actual output `#x added: +1 rep: +1undefined executed[+]` second is identical.

I've tried using `Number(commandName)`, along with `toString().replace(/\D\s/g,'')` I got some promising results but they seemed to have some problems so I scrapped that code...

so in conclusion how can I add the numbers together and avoid the +?

```js
const tmi = require('tmi.js');

// Define configuration options
const opts = {
    identity: {
        username: "x",
        password: "x"
    },
    channels: [
        "#x"
    ]
};

// Create a client with our options
const client = new tmi.client(opts);

// Register our event handlers (defined below)
client.on('message', onMessageHandler);
client.on('connected', onConnectedHandler);

// Connect to Twitch:
client.connect();

const totalnum = 0;
// Called every time a message comes in
function onMessageHandler(target, context, msg, self) {
    if (self) {
        return;
    } // Ignore messages from the bot

    // Remove whitespace from chat message
    let commandName = msg.trim();

    var regexadd = /([+]\d*)[^+\s]/;

    // If the command is known, let's execute it
    if (regexadd.exec(commandName)) {
        var totalnum = addem(commandName, totalnum);
        console.log(target, `added:`, commandName, `rep:`, totalnum, `executed[+]`)
    } else {
        console.log(`* Unknown command ${commandName}`);
    }

    function addem(x, y) {
        return (x + y);
    }


}



// Called every time the bot connects to Twitch chat
function onConnectedHandler(addr, port) {
    console.log(`* Connected to ${addr}:${port}`);
}
```

Comment: Use `parseInt()` to convert a string to a integer. For example, `let str = '+2'; let num = 'parseInt(str, 10);` returns `2` for `num`

Comment: You're not adding numbers. `addem()`'s first parameter should be: `+regexadd.exec(commandName)`.  Additional note: use `regexadd.test(commandName)` for your `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few things that appear to be wrong with your code:

- You're not adding numbers. `addem()`'s first parameter is the name of the command, it should be the number captured in your regex capture group.
- Your regex includes the `+` sign in the capture group, you probably wanted to exclude it
- You should parse the result of exec to a hint either with `ParseInt()` or implicitly with `+`
- You use RegExp.prototype.exec() instead of RegExp.prototype.match() to retrieve a capture group.

Here's what this could look like

```
var regexadd = /\+(\d*)[^+\s]/;    
if (regexadd.exec(commandName)) {
   var totalnum = addem(+commandName.match(regexadd)[1], totalnum);
   console.log(target, `added:`, commandName, `rep:`, totalnum, `executed[+]`)
}
```

I also think it would be best to use `RegExp.prototype.test()` instead of `RegExp.prototype.exec()` for your `if` statement - you will limit results to true or false.

Comment: How exactly would I parse this, I tried to parse it with a new variable but I get a `variable.match is not a function` same thing when the variable is `commandName` although I can parse commandName after the addem call, which is pointless... Here's the output `#x added: +1000 rep: NaN executed[+]` what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you give me 4 sample input with 4 expected outputs?